# Drop a row with 'n/a' in Time Series Panda Python

Tags: python, row

I read a Panda Time Series where some of the field in the Time Series have the entry 'n/a'.
I want to get rid of all those entries and reindex the Time Series.

```
13
15
47
n/a
temp
car
```

I tried

```
ts.drop('n/a')
```

but it throws the message

```
ValueError: labels ['n/a'] not contained in axis
```

Also tried

```
ts.dropna(how='any')
```

This does not give any error but 'n/a' is not removed

Any help will be great.

Comment: have you tried list.remove('n/a') ?

Comment: It is a time series. It says No Attribute remove